# Dynamically include external Javascript file

Tags: javascript

So I need to dynamically call and execute the javascript code generated from external php file. This is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
id = <some id calculation>;
var code_url = 'http://example.com/javascript.php?id=' + id; // this generates the javascript desired

var code_div = document.getElementById("code_div"); // where I want to insert the JS
var fileref=document.createElement('script');
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
fileref.setAttribute("src", code_url);
code_div.appendChild(fileref);
}
</script>
```

Now the div with the javascript link does show up, but it doesn't seem to execute. I tried going through other similar questions on StackOverflow and other places, but that's as far as it got me. Any idea why it's not executing?

UPDATE: Fixed the missing quote. Also I should've mentioned I placed the code inside the body. I don't have access to the HEAD in my case, and I need to insert the Analytics code

Comment: If that was really what you had, then the div wouldn't show up as the script would error on line one because you forgot the closing quote for the string.

Comment: Oh no sorry... it was error when I edited to script to post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing mistakes (such as missing function declaration, closing quote in your code), make sure your `code_url` reference to a page which has a **function calling** or an **event**;

Ex:

```
function needToExecute() {
    ...
}

needToExecute();
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried that and it didn't work. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but this is the output it spits out:

`<div id="script">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/javascript.php?id=123">
</script>
</div>`

NOTE: I forgot to mention I am attaching dynamic id to the url. Shouldn't make difference to the javascript call should it?
If I run the javascript in separate page, it generates the correct output

Comment: Sure... Here is my simple attempt. It works if I go to the url directly.

`<script type="text/javascript">

function sayHi() {

alert('hi mecca');

}



sayHi();

</script>`

Answer (score 3):

The code should cause the code in the script element to be executed (once the missing quote on line 1 is added), are you sure that's exactly what you have in your page? e.g. the following works:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.type = 'text/javascript';
  s.src = '_foo.js';
  document.body.appendChild(s);
}
```

in `_foo.js`:

```
alert('loaded');
```

Comment: Thanks. tried the window.onload. If I place alert() inside the function, it executes, and the _foo.js alone executes properly. I should note I'm adding dynamic id to the javascript url, forgot to mention that. Does it create problem?

The output I get eventually is

`<div id="script">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/javascript.php?id=123">
</script>
</div>
`

Comment: Adding a search string to the URL should have no effect in the browser other than maybe affecting caching of the resource.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at : http://headjs.com/